# Why create app button is disabled in paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I create an account on paypal developper and a business account but I can't create a rest api app because create app button is disabled could you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: hey dude, have you solve it?. if yes then please help me am having same problem

Comment: Hello,after some days of creating the app the button is activated. It's paypal issue. I don't know the real reasons

Comment: Thank You for your reply

Answer (score 8):

**Dudes**
I tried with Firefox and it worked fine.
I spent 3 hours trying with Chrome and couldn't do that.
Try to use firefox!

Source : https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Getting-started-with-PayPal/Unenable-the-quot-Create-App-quot-in-Rest-Api-app/td-p/1180188

Comment: Confirmed, in Firefox the button is blue, and you can create your app! Thanks, Museer!

Comment: After confirming the email, this method worked. Thanks.

Comment: Still having this issue in chrome, firefox works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: For me worked with chorme

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs , when you have not yet confirmed your Email address with paypal

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Had to log out of the account and log back in and then the button was enabled.

However, the button itself doesn't seem to do anything. Get a spinner animation but nothing happens.